# Django ORM: Count individual entries in related field with condition

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model `Game` and a model `Line`. `Line` has a foreign key to `Game` and a `DateTimeField` called `created` which records when the line was created

I would like to annotate a queryset of Game, to count all Lines in each game that were created after a certain date.

something like

`games = Game.objects.all().annotate(
    recent_lines=Count(lines, filter=Q(lines__created__gt=date_to_check)))`

This does not work as it count ALL the lines as valid...

How can I achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean it counts all the lines as valid? Do you mean it ignores the created date condition and just counts all the lines regardless of whether they were created after the date or not?

Comment: Yes exactly. The value of Count ends up simply being the number of lines in the game, regardless of their date of creation.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that you're using Django < 2.0 which doesn't support the `filter` argument to `Count` (it basically just ignores it). The `filter` argument [was added in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#id6).

[For older versions of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation), you have to use the `Case` and `When` conditional expressions which are a bit more verbose unfortunately, but should do the job.

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Case, When

games = Game.objects.all().annotate(
    recent_lines=Count(Case(
        When(recent_lines__created__gt=date_to_check, then=1), 
        output_field=CharField())))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count lines for each game, you can do like this

```
game = Game.objects.get(id=1)
 Line.objects.filter(game=game,created__gte=datetime.date(2018,2,12).count()
```

Comment: I don't just want to count the lines, I want to annotate the games so that I can later order them based on this number.